# What is the time interval for daily GPM IMERG product? 0:00 to 23:59 local time? UTC?

Tags: time, precipitation, gpm

I'm processing a bunch of GPM IMERG Daily products and comparing to historical station data. These old met stations report daily precip from 9am to 9am of the following day. So I'm wandering what is the time interval cor the daily GPM data? 0:00 to 23:59 local time?

Is there a service that will provide daily GPM data considering other time intervals (i.e. 9am to 9am following day)? Or will I need to download the 30min data and aggregate manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daily IMERG data is based on UTC time. To get custom interval, you need to get the 30min data and aggregate it based on your preference.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar answer from GSFC Staff:

> Hi Daniel - There is ample metadata inside the IMERG Daily files. If
>   you `"ncdump -h"` any of the data files, you'll see global attributes,
>   like
>
> ```
>         :BeginTime = "00:00:00.000Z"
> ```
>
> Where the "Z" in the format above of course indicates "Zulu" which is
>   the same as the UTC. It is not the local time, and it does not
>   observe the Daylight Saving Time.